# Turn Binary Data into Airborne Packets?

Tags: testing, wireless, wireshark, wifi

Are there any software libraries and/or wireless drivers that make it possible to turn a sequence of binary data into a wireless packet in the air?  For example, if someone used **Airpcap** / **Wireshark** to capture a series of interesting packets, is there some library that can be fed that binary data in order to turn it back into 802.11 wireless packets for testing purposes?  If so, can we then also make minor alterations to the values of the packet in order to generate a wide variety of testing scenarios?  Is anyone aware of tools/libraries that enable or assist this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Wi-fi tools are set up for cracking networks or stealing data so you might be able to re-purpose an existing attacker's tool or library (like [ettercap](http://ettercap.sourceforge.net/) or [aircrack-ng](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/)) for your testing purposes. Most tools I've encountered focus on ethernet, tcp and http.

The following list of software might merit further investigation:

1. [TCPReplay](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/)
2. [Bit-Twist](http://bittwist.sourceforge.net/)
3. [aircrack-ng suite](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/)
4. [Nemesis](http://nemesis.sourceforge.net/)
5. [Packet Editor](http://www.packeteditor.com/)

Bit-Twist and TCPReplay are your best bet if you're willing to compromise for something higher up in the protocol stack.

Answer (score 4):

While there are many tools around that may be used to replay and send data, one of the most advanced and flexible one is:

### TCPReplay

http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/

You can edit the packets at different levels and then to send them.

Excerpt from their website:

> ... You can ... classify traffic as client or server, rewrite Layer 2, 3 and 4 headers and finally replay ...

There are some alternatives such as [bitTwist](http://bittwist.sourceforge.net/) and the [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org) library.